# I want to update the xml element's attribute and it's nested elements value within it in C#

Tags: c#, xml, webforms, linq-to-xml

Basically i have created a webform which lets user to add,edit and delete the elements(or records) of an existing xml file by letting user to write his/her data value into textbox.Now problem comes here when i have created a button to edit/update the elements value.whenever this button will be clicked the user will be required to enter the already existing Student element's attribute value of ID which then will be checked in my linq query code as if that ID exists or not, and if it exists all the other nested elements value will be printed for that element into all of the textboxes.
Below is my whole code and xml file too:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="xmlCRUD.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.xmlCRUD" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Student-ID :
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Student Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Gender :<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Total Marks :
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Add Student" />
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Edit Data" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter student-ID" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class xmlCRUD : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var student = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\sample1.xml");
            student.Add(new XElement("Student",
                  new XAttribute("ID", TextBox1.Text),
                  new XElement("Name", TextBox2.Text),
                  new XElement("Gender", TextBox3.Text),
                  new XElement("Marks",TextBox4.Text)
                ));
            student.Save(@"C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\sample1.xml");
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button2.Text = "Update";
           var student = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\sample1.xml");
            string val = from m in student.Elements("Student").Where(x=>x.Attribute("ID").Value == TextBox5.Text).Select(x=>x.Element("Student"));
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Students>
  <Student ID="101">
    <Name>kamal</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <Marks>800</Marks>
  </Student>
  <Student ID="102">
    <Name>Sapna</Name>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <Marks>900</Marks>
  </Student>
  <Student ID="103">
    <Name>Raju</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <Marks>870</Marks>
  </Student>
  <Student ID="104">
    <Name>Sushant</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <Marks>700</Marks>
  </Student>
  
</Students>
```

Please help me in this!

Answer (score 0):

with this code in edit button click event function i did that:

```html
   protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button2.Text = "Update";
           var student = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\sample1.xml");
            var val = (from m in student.Elements("Student") 
                          where (string)m.Attribute("ID") == TextBox5.Text 
                          select m);
            //XElement a = (XElement)val;
            if (val.Any())
            {
                foreach (XElement element in val)
                {
                    TextBox2.Text = element.Element("Name").Value;
                    TextBox3.Text = element.Element("Gender").Value;
                    TextBox4.Text = element.Element("Marks").Value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```